# Why are Nested Comments forbidden?

Tags: programming-languages, comments, language-features

Why are nested comments forbidden in C++, Java inspite of the fact that nested comments are useful, neat, and elegant and can be used to comment out statements that have comments?

Comment: "fact"?  Really?

Comment: Rust is one language that supports nested block comments, despite having a C-based syntax

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C and C++ do it for ease of parsing. This way, when they hit a comment start of /*, the parser can trivially scan to the end. Otherwise, it would have to set up and maintain a stack, and then report errors if the comment tokens are unmatched.

As to why Java does it, the answer is simple - Java's syntax was designed to emulate C and C++. If nested comments were allowed, it might trip up some C programmers, and many angry blog posts would be written!

Comment: Why would you need a stack to handle nested comments? Just maintain a counter, incrementing it each time you encounter a `/*` and decrementing it each time you encounter a `*/`. When the counter is greater than zero you throw out any characters you find (while still keeping track of `/*` and `*/`); when the counter is zero you read tokens normally and hand them to the parser; if the counter becomes negative you report a mismatch between comment delimiters. You do this during lexical analysis, so the parser never even sees the comments.

Answer (score 9):

At least for C++ that's only partly true, there's no problem with:

```
/*
//
//
*/
```

However if you already got an /* comment in a section you want to comment out you might be able to do it by surrounding it with an `#if 0` which I think many compilers optimize away. As in:

```
#if 0
/*

*/
#endif
```

Comment: ALL compilers optimize that away, in the same way they "optimize" away multiple includes when header guards are used, as it's part of the preprocessing step.

Comment: Compilers will not see this block, the *preprocessor* will have removed it before a compiler will lay its eyes on the code :).

Comment: @wowus: Yes, you're right of course. I was thinking of `if(0)` which I think is compiler dependent.

Answer (score 5):

It is different for each language(-family) but in general they are not 'forbidden' but simply not supported. Supporting them is a design choice.

One reason for the choice (for older languages) may have been ease of parsing.

Note: I remember a C++ compiler where it was an option to let them nest. It was marked as 'non standard'.

Answer (score 3):

Conformance/compatibility with C.

Comment: Didn't C only originally use the // comment symbol?  Also, why would Java need to conform to the C standard?

Comment: @tloach: `//` does not exist in C before C99.

Comment: C originally used only /* */, and Java was intentionally patterned after C (and C++) to make it more familiar to existing programmers.  Conform is probably too strong of a word here, but I'm not sure what would be better.

Comment: @tloach - no. Originally C only had /* */ comments - which is why they are called C style comments. Most early C compilers also allowed them to be nested and many - gcc for example - still do for backward compatibility.

Comment: Ok, I had my comment styles mixed up apparently :)  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following example:

```
/* This is a comment /* Nested Comments */ are not allowed. */
```

Anything which lies between `/*` and `*/` is treated as a comment. In the above example from `This` up to `Comments` everything is treated as comments including `/*`. 
Hence, `are not allowed. */` does not lie in the comment. 
This being an improper C statement error occurs.

While consider this example:

```
// This is an /* valid */ comment
```

Whatever lies in the line after `//` is treated as comment. Since `/* valid */` lies in the same line after `//` , it is treated as part of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

In languages which allow arbitrary-length comments, it is very common for programmers to accidentally comment out or, in some rare cases, "uncomment back in" more or less code than desired.  In many cases, such mistakes will result in compilation errors, but in other cases they may result in code which is simply broken.  With modern syntax-highlighting editors, a rule that each `/*` would increment a nested-comments counter and each `*/` which would decrement it might not cause too much trouble, but without syntax highlighting even trying to figure out what code is commented and what code wasn't could be a major headache.

If one were designing a language from scratch, a good approach might be to specify start-of-comment and end-of-comment marks that included an optional string, and have the language enforce a requirement that the string in an end-of-comment mark must match the string in its corresponding start-of-comment mark.  Assuming the syntax was `<|String|` and `|String|>`, a compiler could then accept `<|1| <|2| |2|> |1|>`, but reject `<|1| <|2| |1|> |2|>`.  Even if one favored the use of `#if` directives rather than comments, the ability to attach markers to ensure that each end-directive was matched up with the intended start directive would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you can't simply "skip" blocks. blocks have unknown number of blocks inside of them, so in order to know when that block is complete, you can't use a regular language, you have to use a stack and walk through each block until the stack is empty, at which point you know  that the block is done.

The reason why you can't skip blocks is that the regular expression for the block is only capable of matching the /* with either "the first */ it sees afterwards" or "the last */ it sees afterwards" or "nth */ it sees afterwards".

If we go with the first "*/" token we see, we may have code like

```
/*
    /*

    */
    the compiler matched /* with */ and this line and the next one will confuse it.
*/
```

If we go with the last "*/" token we see, we have code where the compiler will skip things between the first comment in the file and the last comment of the file's end. In this case, the following code would be parsed as an empty string.

```
/*
    /* hello, world! */
*/
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    return 0;
}
/* end of file */
```

We can't go with the third option of skip n inner blocks without forcing all comments to have exact number of depth, otherwise it will not find the inner comment and get confused.

Actually, there is a fourth option of explicitly stating that a comment can be a single comment, a 2-scope comment, a 3-scope comment, etc; But doing this is a ugly, and each level of depth requires a significantly longer expression, and this approach limits comments to a specific depth which may fit some people, and not fit others: What if you comment out a code that has been commented out 3 times?

The general solution can be implemented with a pre-preprocessor such as:

```
<?php
function stripComments($code) {
    $stack = array();
    $codeOut = '';
    $stringStream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
    fwrite($stringStream, $code);  
    rewind($stringStream);  

    while (!feof($stringStream)) {
        $ch = fgetc($stringStream);

        $nextChar = fgetc($stringStream);
        if ($nextChar === false) {
            break;
        }

        if ($ch == '/' && $nextChar == '*') {
            array_push($stack, '/*');          
        } else if ($ch == '*' && $nextChar == '/') {
            if (count($stack) > 0) {
                array_pop($stack);
            } else {
                die('cannot pop from empty stack');
            }
        } else {
            if (count($stack) == 0) {
                $codeOut .= $ch;
                fseek($stringStream, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            }
        }               

        $prevChar = $ch;
    }
    return $codeOut;
};
?>
```

Which is slightly more complicated than what C currently uses:

```
function stripComments($code) {
    return preg_replace('/\/\*[^\*\/]*\*\//', '', $code);
}
```

This does not take into consideration `/**/` blocks inside quotes, a slightly more complicated stack that can distinguish between "/*" scope and "\"" scope is required.

The benefit of having comments inside comments is that you can comment out blocks that contain comments without stripping the comments manually, which is particularly frustrating for blocks that have comment on every line.

**Summary**: It can be done, but most languages do not want to treat comments as if they were their own scopes, as it takes more effort to parse.